# Trying to send email with Gmail STP (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, smtp, gmail

I'm trying to send some emails from my web application. Here is my configuration:

```
//config/environments/development.rb
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
port:                 587,
domain:               'domain.com',
user_name:            'myusername',
password:             'mypassword',
authentication:       'plain',
enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

---

```
// mailers/contact_mailer
class ContactMailer < ApplicationMailer
default from: 'from@gmail.com'

def send_email()
    mail(to: 'to@gmail.com', subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
end
end
```

---

```
// views/contact_mailer/send_email.html.erb
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv='Content-Type' />
</head>
<body>
<h1>Welcome to example.com, name</h1>
<p>
<p>Thanks for joining and have a great day!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

---

So to test it, I ran this command from the Rails command:

```
ContactMailer.send_email
```

And I'm getting this result:

```
irb(main):003:0> ContactMailer.send_email
Rendered contact_mailer/send_email.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.1ms)

ContactMailer#send_email: processed outbound mail in 10.4ms
=> #<Mail::Message:69980432504260, Multipart: false, Headers: <From:    adib.elaraki@gmail.com>, <To: adib.amine.mdr@gmail.com>, <Subject: Welcome   to My Awesome Site>, <Mime-Version: 1.0>, <Content-Type: text/html>>
irb(main):004:0>
```

Unfortunately, after checking my email, I don't receive the email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mail` only generates a mailer object. You need to append something like `deliver_now` for it to actually send. For example:

```
ContactMailer.send_email.deliver_now
```

Comment: Seems better, but i now got this error : Net::SMTPAuthenticationError: 534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/signin/continue?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbsh. However i did enable the protocols  POP/IMAP from my gmail account..

Comment: I'm assuming you've changed your login details from it actually being
    domain:               'domain.com',
    user_name:            'myusername',
    password:             'mypassword',
?

Comment: I also remember needing to do something like this https://support.google.com/a/answer/6260879?hl=en when I set up SMTP, but disable at your own risk.